# How to manipulate data from get Functions in C++?

Tags: c++, object

For instance:

I want to substract from array, `account[1].GetBalance`.

When I try to do `account[1].GetBalance = account[1].GetBalance - withdrawal`, it says the expression is not assignable.

How do I obtain the value in `account[1].GetBalance` to manipulate the data?

```
void Account::SetBalance(double balance)
{

    balance_ = balance;

}

double Account::GetBalance()
{

    return balance_;

}
```

Comment: Is `GetBalance` a variable or a function?

Comment: Is there a SetBalance?

Comment: Dont you have a set balance function? Also is get balance in the above function calls?

Comment: How did you come by this code without understanding how functions in C++ work? Are you a C#/VB programmer working thru a "Learning C++" book? Not asking to be mean, but you really seem to have missed some fundamentals arriving at the code above; please consider reviewing the pages you skipped in the last chapter or so.

Comment: Admittedly, skipping around on the chapters.

But I am going back and reading previous chapters now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is that GetBalance is a member function.

You'll need to write a SetBalance function that takes the new balance as an argument, and use parenthises after GetBalance:

```
account[1].SetBalance(account[1].GetBalance() - withdrawal)
```

Even better, put a method on your Account object to do the withdrawal for you:

```
void Account::Withdraw(int amount)
{
    m_balance -= amount;
}
```

Then,

```
account[1].Withdraw(withdrawal);
```

Comment: I had no idea you could nest a function within a function like that! That is brilliant.

Normally, I would create a function for it but I'm uncertain whether or not we're allowed to do so.

Comment: No, don't nest it. Keep code where it belongs - with the rest of its implementation. Was just meaning to show you the relevant snippets.

Comment: Perhaps "nest" was the wrong word.

I already had a SetBalance function, so the top line of code you listed worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

```
account[1].SetBalance(account[1].GetBalance() - withdraw);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing basically you want to return an lvalue

```
double& Account::GetBalance()
{

    return balance_;

}
```

Now this `account[1].GetBalance() = account[1].GetBalance() - withdrawal()` should work

Comment: Have you tried it? It still doesn't compile. (And your method is bad style - it's equivalent to making your data public)

Comment: I dont know why you say its bad style , if we want the data to be exposed we have to,
many places we have this requirements for example if you see 
operator[] in vectors & maps they have lvalues [aka refrences being retuned ]

Comment: It's bad style because `GetX/SetX` should (are expected to) work as a pair. If I read a bit of code and see that it calls `GetX` but not `SetX`, I assume that `X` is unchanged. This style assumption does not hold for `[]`, as that has been used in both roles since C arrays.